# How to return list of namespaces in System.Collections assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

This code does not return any namespaces, when called for System.Collections.

```
public static List<string> GetAssemblyNamespaces(AssemblyName asmName)
{
  List<string> namespaces = new List<string>();
  Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(asmName);

  foreach (Type typ in asm.GetTypes())
    if (typ.Namespace != null) 
      if (!namespaces.Contains(typ.Namespace))
        namespaces.Add(typ.Namespace);

  return namespaces;
}
```

Why is that? There are types in System.Collections. What can I do instead to get the namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

Different assemblies may contain the same(or sub) namespaces. For ex `A.dll` may contain the namespace `A` and `B.dll` may contain `A.B`. So you have to load *all* assemblies to be able to find namespaces.

This may do the trick, but it still has the problem that namespace can be in a not-referenced, not-used assembly.

```
var assemblies = new List<AssemblyName>(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies());
assemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName());

var nss = assemblies.Select(name => Assembly.Load(name))
            .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())
            .Where(type=>type.Namespace!=null)
            .Where(type=>type.Namespace.StartsWith("System.Collections"))
            .Select(type=>type.Namespace)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

For example, If you run above code, you will not get `System.Collections.MyCollections` since it is defined in my test code `SO.exe` :)

Comment: But if I only want the namespaces in System.Collections.dll, why would I need to load any other assemblies? According to documentation (.NET 4.5), this assembly contains five namespaces (System.Collections, System.Collections.Concurrent, System.Collections.Generic, System.Collections.ObjectModel, System.Collections.Specialized). Do you mean they are not in System.Collections.dll, but in some other assembly referenced by System.Collections.dll?! But the main question is really why GetTypes() does not return any types. There are types in System.Collections.dll, like ArrayList, Stack etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var namespaces = assembly.GetTypes()
                         .Select(t => t.Namespace)
                         .Distinct();
```

by using `LINQ` you can get the namespace of the assemly.

Comment: That's just another way to write the code. It still should return 0 namespaces for System.Collections assembly.